# Can't loop form_row in twig

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I Want To Loop a Form_row In SF2/Twig :

The Code:

```
{% for post in posts %}
            {{ form_row(formreply.body) }}
{% endfor %}
```

I Have A timeline How contient Many Post But It show me the Form Only for the first Status on timeline ,

**UPDATE :**

The problem is not in the Posts loop ::

An other example :

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
    {{ form_row(formreply.body) }}
{% endfor %}
```

It should show Me the Form_Row Ten times , right ?

It show it for me only one time ..

note 'I have returned the formreply In the Controller'

Comment: You can only render a field ONE time... Are you talking about embedded form for collection ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot loop a form_row like that. Form row can be rendered only once. If you try to create same form multiple times for each PostReply and  render them in a loop - it won't work again, because you will get same ID's and field names.

I'm assuming you have collection of posts, and you want to show them in the timeline style, with reply field rendered next to each post. To achieve that I suggest you create PostReply entity and PostReplyType (form type). As I said earlier you have to use dynamic name generation.

This should give you an idea in which direction you should go:

```
class Post
{
    private $id;
    private $title;
}

class PostReply
{
    private $id;
    private $postId;
    private $message;
}

class PostReplyType extends AbstractType
{
    private $name = 'reply_form';

    public function setName($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    // builder and other required code
}
```

Then you will be able to do something like this in your controller:

```
$posts = $postsRepository->findAll();
$postReplyForms = new ArrayCollection();

foreach($posts as $post) {
    $postReply = new PostReply();
    $postReplyType = new PostReplyType();
    $postReplyType->setName('reply_form_' . $post->getId());
    $form = $this->createForm($postReplyType, $postReply);
    $postReplyForms->add($form);
}
```

In twig:

```
{% for form in postReplyForms %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endfor %}
```

This should render forms with dynamic ID's and names as :

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="reply_form_1_field" name="reply_form_1[field]"/>
</form>
<form>
<input type="text" id="reply_form_2_field" name="reply_form_2[field]"/>
</form>
```

Symfony2 forms are very complex part of the framework, I recommend beginning with documentation to get basic understanding of how SF2 forms work. Then googling for more use cases. Good luck.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: This is what I want , Thanks Bro :)

Comment: Just Question : Can I add This attr directly on twig , I mean like this : 
{{ form_widget(formreply.body, { 'name': 'my custom name ' }) }}
Thanks again :)