# Customize Row's ID attribute in Twig

Tags: html, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

Is it possible to customize HTML 'name' attribute in Twig when rendering a widget with `{{ form_widget(form.NAME_OF_THE_FIELD) }}` ?

Passing `{ 'name': 'my custom name ' }) }` doesn't work...
Or  `{'attr': {'name': 'SOMETHING'}}` also doesn't work...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony Form Class: rename fields name attribute's value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773524/symfony-form-class-rename-fields-name-attributes-value)

Comment: Thanks , But i think that the first answer more easy , right ? :)

Comment: The @qooplmao is a better answer that this duplicate.

Comment: yeah , always thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The "name" is stored in the field vars under the "full_name" key so to customise it in your Twig file you can use..

```
{{ form_widget(form.NAME_OF_THE_FIELD, {'full_name': 'A DIFFERENT NAME' }) }}
```

**NOTE**

Changing the automatically generated "name" of a field wouldn't be recommend as, due to it not being expected by the form, it will not be picked up when submitting your form data.

Comment: It works , Thanks :) , But can i  loop the form When i use this :)

Comment: You can do whatever you want, it's only a static bit of text. If you are wanting to use the loop reference in the name then you could do something like `{'full_name': 'dynamic_name_' ~ loop.index }`. If you're after something else I would recommend adding to your question or creating a new one.

Comment: I'm really post a One : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018922/cant-loop-form-row-in-twig 
thanks

Comment: @hassenzouari As you seems to be new here, don't forget to accept this answer if it solves your problem. (at the left of the answer, bellow the point)

Comment: of course , But when i create a new post reply It doesn't work :( even don't loop the form_row ...